# Python HTML parsing: getting site top level hosts

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a program that takes in a site's source code/html and outputs the a href tags - it is extremely helpful and makes use of BeautifulSoup4.

I am wanting to have a variation of this code that only looks at < a href="..."> tags but **returns just top directory host names from a site's source codes**, for example

```
stackoverflow.com
google.com
```

etc. but NOT lower level ones like stackoverflow.com/questions/ etc. Right now it's outputting everything, including /, #t8 etc. and I need to filter them out.

Here is my current code I use to extract all a href tags.

```
url = sys.argv[1] #when program is invoked, takes it in like www.google.com etc.
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# get hosts
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print a['href']
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `.netloc` attribute of `urlparse`. It's part of the Python standard library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

For example:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351727/python-html-parsing-getting-site-top-level-hosts"
>>> urlparse(url).netloc
'stackoverflow.com'
```